# XML Schema errors in validation

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have been practicing coding schemas for XML. So far, I have made progress. When I try to validate my schema, I am getting 3 errors which I do not understand.

customer.xml

```
<customerinfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="customer.xsd">
        <customer reference="A1">
            <fullname>
                <title>Miss</title>
                <firstname>Summer</firstname>
                <middlename>K</middlename>
                <lastname>Simpson</lastname>
            </fullname>
            <address>
                <street>12 Blood Street</street>
                <suburb>Melbourne</suburb>
                <postcode>1111</postcode>
                <state>VIC</state>
            </address>
            <contact>
                <phone>123456789</phone>
                <phone>123456789</phone>
                <phone>123456789</phone>
            </contact>
            <meter number="1">
            <reading>
                <date>2019-10-03</date>
                <meterread>100</meterread>
                <amtdue>100.00</amtdue>
                <paymentdate>2019-10-03</paymentdate>
                <amtpaid>100.00</amtpaid>
            </reading>
            <reading>
                <date>2019-10-03</date>
                <meterread>100</meterread>
                <amtdue>100.00</amtdue>
                <paymentdate>2019-10-03</paymentdate>
                <amtpaid>100.00</amtpaid>
            </reading>
            </meter>
        </customer>
        <customer reference="A2">
            <fullname>
                <title>Miss</title>
                <firstname>April</firstname>
                <middlename>P</middlename>
                <lastname>Duck</lastname>
            </fullname>
            <address>
                <street>32 Cardigan Street</street>
                <suburb>Wonderland</suburb>
                <postcode>9000</postcode>
                <state>SA</state>
            </address>
            <contact>
                <phone>123456789</phone>
            </contact>
            <meter number="2">
            <reading>
                <date>2019-10-03</date>
                <meterread>100</meterread>
                <amtdue>100.00</amtdue>
                <paymentdate>2019-10-03</paymentdate>
                <amtpaid>100.00</amtpaid>
            </reading>
            </meter>
        </customer>
</customerinfo>
```

customer.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>     
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="customerinfo">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="customer"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="customer">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="fullname"/>
   <xs:element name="address"/>
   <xs:element name="contact"/>
   <xs:element name="meter"/>
  </xs:sequence>
   <xs:attribute name="reference" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="fullname">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="middlename" type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="address">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="suburb" type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="postcode" type="xs:integer"/>
   <xs:element name="state" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="contact">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="phone" type="xs:integer" maxOccurs="3"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="meter">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="reading" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
   <xs:attribute name="number" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="reading">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="date" type="xs:date"/>
   <xs:element name="meterread" type="xs:integer"/>
   <xs:element name="amtdue" type="xs:decimal"/>
   <xs:element name="paymentdate" type="xs:date"/>
   <xs:element name="amtpaid" type="xs:decimal"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

The errors are:

> Attribute 'reference' Must Appear On Element 'customerinfo'.

I don't understand this one because I have stated the attribute reference

> Invalid Content Was Found Starting With Element 'customer'. One Of '{fullname}' Is Expected.

I don't understand this one because I have stated the element fullname

> Invalid Content Was Found Starting With Element 'reading'. No Child Element Is Expected At This Point.

I don't understand this one either because reading does have numerous children such as date, meterread, amdue, paymentdate and amtpaid?

Edit: I have managed to fix the errors above, however now I am getting a new error. I have also updated my xsd file in the post.

Invalid content was found starting with element 'customer'. No child element is expected at this point.

The element customer does have children: fullname, address, contact & meter.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have an attribute `reference` on the `customer` element, but not on the `customerinfo` element.
2. The schema says the `customerinfo` element should start with a `fullname` child, but in the instance the child element is named `customer`.
3. The schema says that the `meter` element must have a single `reading` child but your instance has multiple `reading` children.

Comment: Was about to ask OP whether XML or XSD was to be changed, but this ought to cover either.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have managed to fix the errors above, however now I am getting a new error. I have also updated my xsd file in the post.

Invalid content was found starting with element 'customer'. No child element is expected at this point.

The element customer does have children: fullname, address, contact & meter.